# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions - when calling Session.update()

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, playframework

I have 2 entities : `User` and `Player`

`User` entity has a `@OneToOne` relationship with `Player` and `Player` has a `@OneToOne` relationship to `User`.

For optimization purposes I store my `User`s in cache and I try to retrieve them for each request.

Because the retrieve entity (from cache) is detached from the current hibernate `Session` I call the `update()` method of the current `Session` to re-attach it.

To avoid errors I also check if the entity is not already attached to the session with the `contains()` method of the `Session` object.

Here is a code sample to show you how I proceed:

```
User user = User.getCached(User.class, userId);
if (user == null) {
    user = User.find("from User user left join fetch user.player where user.id = ?", userId).first();
    user = User.addToCache(User.class, user);
}
if (!getSession().contains(user.player))
    getSession().update(user.player);   // Throws the exception
```

This code is called to retrieve the connected user. It first tries to retrieve it from cache. If the user is not in cache I load it from database and insert it in cache. Then I update the entity to attach it to the session if it is not attached.

Sometimes the `update()` method throws the following exception when I call it: `Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions`

Does it mean that the player is already attached to the session?
If yes, why did the `contains()` method returned false then?
If no, why do I get this exception? And how to avoid it?

**EDIT**

When I get this exception, if I try to modify my entity's value and call `save()` I have another exception saying that the entity is detached. How can it be detached if the previous exception says it's already associated to a session?

PS: I can only have 1 session per thread

Comment: Both user and player are initially session bound. Maybe you want to cache a user (BareUser) without player, just a player ID.

Comment: Actually I would like the player to be stored in cache too with the user. Why would it change something to exclude it from cache?

Comment: Why are you caching the users, if you update them anyway? Retrieving a user from the session should have similar costs - without the concurrency issues you are dealing with now.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I cache my users because I don't update them often. However I'm wondering if it's worth caching the users myself because I think Hibernate is also using some cache system. Do you think the Hibernate cache system can be as efficient as my cache system?

Comment: It uses serialization, which takes some time. So the caching is slower than your approach - but it is much faster than the update you are doing and it has no concurrency problems - so it should be the better solution.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke maybe you're right, I should get rid of my cache system to rely on hibernate's one. I'll take some time to think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a concurrency problem here: imagine having multiple parallel HTTP requests that request the same `User`. The solution would to use some [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: Your answer is interesting, I didn't think about it. I tried to make my cached entities thread safe (using ThreadLocal<User>), but I still get the exception (less often than before however). I'm gonna investigate a little bit more but I think I will make your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Try synchronizing the entire method (as I understand the posted code is part of a single method) for a quick test.

Comment: I marked your answer because even if I couldn't make it fully work yet, multithreading seems to be the problem here. I'll continue woking on it

Answer (score 1):

The *update* method has many shortcomings:

- it always try to issue an update when using detached objects, as otherwise it can't tell if something has changed while the entity was detached
- it may conflict with an already loaded entity copy

That's why [*merge* is a better alternative](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), because [*merge* works like this](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/):

- The merge is going to copy the detached entity state (source) to a managed entity instance (destination). If the merging entity has no equivalent in the current Session, one will be fetched from the database. The detached object instance will continue to remain detached even after the merge operation.

So the *merge* operation is much safer and if the entity hasn't changed, while it was detached, the [dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) will prevent an unnecessary UPDATE.

Comment: Actually in my cache system, as soon as the entity is updated the cache is cleared so that the entity is retrieved from database next time. That's why I'm using update: I don't want the entity to be retrieved from the database because I know it has not changed

Answer (score 0):

1_ try to clear the session before retrieving the user

2_ add CascadeType.DETACH to the @OneToOne annotation.